# ORACLE 10.2 Pro*C precompiler not reading header file

Tags: oracle, oracle-pro-c

I'm pre-compiling a C program containing Pro*C code with Oracle 10.2 and AIX 5.2

The Oracle precompiler reads the `$ORACLE_HOME/precomp/admin/pcscfg.cfg file` which contains the definition of the sys_include variable (set to `/usr/include`).

The Pro*C compiler complains that it doesn't know what the `size_t` type is and the Oracle header files that use the `size_t` type are reporting errors.

Here's an example error being reported on the `sqlcpr.h` file:

```
extern void sqlglm( char*, size_t*, size_t* );
...........................1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "size_t" when expecting one of the following
```

`size_t` is defined in the `stdio.h` header file in the `/usr/include` directory. I'm including the `stdio.h` header in my `example.pc` file before I include the `sqlcpr.h` header.

I'm issuing the proc command as follows:

```
proc iname=example parse=full
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Metalink](https://metalink2.oracle.com/metalink/plsql/f?p=130:3:9328216730994661370::::p3_database_id,p3_docid,p3_show_header,p3_show_help,p3_black_frame,p3_font:NOT,102288.1,1,1,1,helvetica)

```
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "size_t" when expecting one of the 
following
:
   ... auto, char, const, double, enum,  float, int, long,
   ulong_varchar, OCIBFileLocator OCIBlobLocator,
   OCIClobLocator, OCIDateTime, OCIExtProcContext, OCIInterval,
   OCIRowid, OCIDate, OCINumber, OCIRaw, OCIString, register,
   short, signed, sql_context, sql_cursor, static, struct,
   union, unsigned, utext, uvarchar, varchar, void, volatile,
   a typedef name, exec oracle, exec oracle begin, exec,
   exec sql, exec sql begin, exec sql type, exec sql var,
The symbol "enum," was substituted for "size_t" to continue.
Syntax error at line 88, column 7, file /usr/include/gconv.h:
Error at line 88, column 7 in file /usr/include/gconv.h
                                  size_t *);
```

> ### Solution Description
>
> **The 'sys_include' and 'include' precompiler options are not set 
>   correctly.**  Set 'sys_include' and 'include' precompiler options 
>   in the pcscfg.cfg file located at $ORACLE_HOME/precomp/admin or
>   include on the command line when invoking 'proc'.
>
> For example, here is a recommended way to set the variable properly:
>
> **Run the following command to obtain the compiler location:**
>
> gcc -v
>
> Reading specs from /usr/lib/gcc-lib/i386-redhat-linux7/2.96/specs
>   gcc version 2.96 20000731 (Red Hat Linux 7.3 2.96-128)
>
> **Use the path returned above (remove specs and replace with include)**

```
sys_include=($ORACLE_HOME/precomp/public,
             /usr/lib/gcc-lib/i386-redhat-linux7/2.96/include, 
             /usr/include)

include=(/u02/app/oracle/product/8.1.5/precomp/public)
include=(/u02/app/oracle/product/8.1.5/rdbms/demo)
include=(/u02/app/oracle/product/8.1.5/network/public)
include=(/u02/app/oracle/product/8.1.5/plsql/public)
```

I am guessing that the part of having both sysinclude and include is your issue.

Answer (score 4):

You have to make sure that the include search path is setup such that all needed directories are included in the right order by Pro*C.

For example on CentOS 6.5 I specify following order (in the `pcscfg.cf`):

```
sys_include=$ORACLE_HOME/sdk/include
sys_include=/usr/include
sys_include=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include
sys_include=/usr/include/linux
ltype=short
define=__x86_64__
```

This configuration file is read by `proc` from `$ORACLE_HOME/precomp/admin/pcscfg.cfg`.

Apparently, the default file written by the Oracle installer is often suboptimal, because it e.g. lists a non-existing GCC path and/or uses a problematic include path order.

With a different order I get the same `size_t` related error messages (when permuting the first 4 lines to (1,2,4,3) ).

When permuting the first 4 lines to (1,3,2,4) and including `<limits.h>`, `proc` even goes into an memory allocating infinite loop until it is killed by the OOM killer.

As a workaround you can also specify the `sys_include` option on the `proc` command line, e.g:

```
lines=yes \
code=ANSI_C \
sqlcheck=full \
parse=full \
sys_include=$(ORACLE_HOME)/precomp/public \
sys_include=/usr/include \
sys_include=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include \
sys_include=/usr/include/linux
```

Answer (score 1):

Two thing worth noting when I playing with my pcscfg.cfg file.

1 Remember it doesn't support "space", so any path including space should be written in "short" style. e.g.: `SYS_INCLUDE=D:\Progra~1\Micros~1.0\VC\include`
You can use dir /x in windows to get the short version of the names

2 It appears, in my case at least, INCLUDE should be written before all those options stuff. I.E. If

```
define=(WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN)
parse=full
SYS_INCLUDE=D:\Progra~1\Micros~1.0\VC\include
```

doesn't work, try

```
define=(WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN)
SYS_INCLUDE=D:\Progra~1\Micros~1.0\VC\include
parse=full
```

Instead.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue ("PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol ..."). I listened to both pieces of advice above.

- Check the `sys_include` and make sure the directory path is the one that compiler is actually is set to use. Defaults used by Pro*C generally do not exist. Compile a 'Hello World' program with `gcc -v -c <prog.c>` and check `COMPILER_PATH`
- I adjusted the order of options and brought `sys_include` up in the order (not really sure if should matter, but still.)

so the PCC-S-02201 went away.

Answer (score 0):

I modified placing /usr/include/linux before everything else.  This cleared both the failure to find stddef.h and not knowing what  size_t was. Placing it next to /usr/include only fixed the former.

Modified pcscfg.cfg:

sys_include=(**/usr/include/linux,**$ORACLE_HOME/precomp/public,/usr/include,/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.1/include,/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/3.4.5/include,/usr/lib/gcc-lib/i386-redhat-linux/3.2.3/include,/usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.1.2/include,/usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.3/include)
ltype=short

(CentOS 6.3, oracle 11g)

Answer (score 0):

Use sys_include for the path containing environment variables or Visual Studio variables. If the path is simple path, use "include", else use "sys_include"

I have this issue on Visual Studio 2013, for compiling .pc files, with the above change, all got worked.

Answer (score 0):

Add one compile flag line to `pcscfg.cfg` to make Oracle's precompiler compile with no system header file syntax errors:

```
define=_POSIX_C_SOURCE
```

That's it. It should now precompile without error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue:

```
[me@somesys:~/proC]$ proc sys_include='(/usr/include,/usr/include/linux,/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/x86_64-redhat-linux,/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/tr1,/usr/include/c++/4.8.2)' copy.pc

Pro*C/C++: Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on Thu Jun 6 17:47:11 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

System default option values taken from: /oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/precomp/admin/pcscfg.cfg

Syntax error at line 307, column 3, file /usr/include/libio.h:
Error at line 307, column 3 in file /usr/include/libio.h
  size_t __pad5;
..1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "size_t" when expecting one of the following
:

   } char, const, double, enum, float, int, long, ulong_varchar,
   OCIBFileLocator OCIBlobLocator, OCIClobLocator, OCIDateTime,
   OCIExtProcContext, OCIInterval, OCIRowid, OCIDate, OCINumber,
...
```

And I did as yogmk suggested:

```
[me@somesys:~/proC]$ gcc -v -c borrame.c
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada,go,lto --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/isl-install --with-cloog=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/cloog-install --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=x86-64 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36) (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-c' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/cc1 -quiet -v borrame.c -quiet -dumpbase borrame.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase borrame -version -o /tmp/cc2WTuu6.s
GNU C (GCC) version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36) (x86_64-redhat-linux)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36), GMP version 6.0.0, MPFR version 3.1.1, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../x86_64-redhat-linux/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C (GCC) version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36) (x86_64-redhat-linux)
...
```

But instead of `COMPILER_PATH`, I copied, in order, the non-empty directories after `#include <...> search starts here:`, and it worked!

```
[me@somesys:~/proC]$ proc sys_include='(/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include,/usr/include)' copy.pc

Pro*C/C++: Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on Thu Jun 6 17:54:50 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

System default option values taken from: /oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/precomp/admin/pcscfg.cfg

[me@somesys:~/proC]$
```

Hope it helps anyone.